# why is Ubuntu 12.10/12.04.1 adding unsupported updates by default?

Tags: unity, update-manager, software-sources, unsupported-packages

after installing Ubuntu 12.04.1 and 12.10 respectively for over a few times, i noticed that within the Software Sources, by default, the Unsupported Updates (precise backports / quantal backports) are ticked.

[image: unsupported ticked]

By removing that source BEFORE applying the system updates, i can clearly say that it stopped many issues, like a lack of wifi driver recognition (see here: [WiFi problem after Ubuntu 12.10 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205670/wifi-problem-after-ubuntu-12-10-update) ) or other issues - from originally occurring.

Is there any plan to update this issue towards Raring? By this i call to simply tick the *-security and *-updates only.

[image: how it should be, IMO]

cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design.

From the [12.04 Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop/UbuntuDesktop-12.04)

> Backports are now more easily accessible -- to enable users to more easily receive new versions of software, the Ubuntu Backports repository is now enabled by default. Packages from backports will not be installed by default — they must explicitly be selected in package management software. However, once installed, packages from backports will automatically be upgraded to newer versions.

PS: I very much doubt there is anything related to wireless (or any kind of drivers) in the backports.

PPS: Not sure what's going to happen in Raring.

Comment: so why not mark also the *-proposed source?