# Ubuntu 12.10 HP Pavilion dm4 wireless not working

Tags: 12.10, wireless, hp

I have a HP Pavilion dm4 that initially came with Windows 7. I upgraded to Windows 8 and then replaced that with Ubuntu 12.10. The WiFi worked fine until I installed the software upgrades right after installing the os. There is a hardware switch for WiFi and Bluetooth and it is on.

`rfkill list all` results:

```
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

In the Network settings, I only see Wired and Network Proxy, no wireless. I am currently connected to a wired network to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By typing the command :

```
lspci
```

You can check what kind of wireless card your HP pavillon have. I guess it's probably something like bcm43xx.

If so, the answer to get your wifi working is :

```
sudo apt-get install linux linux-headers-generic kernel-package
sudo apt-get purge b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43-lpphy-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer bcmwl*
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer bcmwl*
```

Reboot !

From [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205670/wifi-problem-after-ubuntu-12-10-update) on askubuntu.com

Comment: also worked for a pavilion dm1 br version with ubuntu 12.04 LTS, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the internet by some other way and install the 4.8+ kernel

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

You also need firmware for this device. Update your system by

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

and the firmware will be installed.

Reboot and the wireless device should work.

To get it working out of the box, you need to install Ubuntu 16.04.2+ that has support of this device.

(I used a USB Ethernet connector for internet access. )

The updates would take a while to get done.