# Ubuntu 12.10 Wireless Problem; only showing me Bluetooth option

Tags: 12.10, wireless, command-line, bluetooth

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 15R. I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 a week ago, and realized that the option for wireless is not there. Not even in the network settings, so I went through the problems posted earlier and I thought its because of Broadcom. So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

But still the wifi is not working.

When I typed `rfkill list all` in the terminal I got the following output...

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth  
Soft blocked: yes  
Hard blocked: no
```

It's showing me only bluetooth and nothing about wireless. I guess wireless is blocked somewhere.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

follow the below link, It may be usefull..... :)
http://technotranz.blogspot.in/2013/02/ubuntu-1210-wireless-problem-solved.html

Comment: Software sources is also not showing me the Broadcom option....I can't upload the photo of the software sources because I don't have much reputations....

Answer (score 0):

By typing the command :

```
lspci
```

You can check what kind of wireless card your Dell Inspiron 15R have. I guess it's probably something like bcm43xx.

If so, the answer to get your wifi working is :

```
sudo apt-get install linux linux-headers-generic kernel-package
sudo apt-get purge b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43-lpphy-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer bcmwl*
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer bcmwl*
```

**Reboot** !

You can also try a `sudo rfkill unblock all` it helped me once with my inspiron 15R.

From [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205670/wifi-problem-after-ubuntu-12-10-update) on askubuntu.com

Comment: Its still not working.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this on my computer today, though it might not be the same problem you're having:

Windows does a thing where it locks up the wireless card, even after windows has been turned off. So if you have a dual-boot system of any kind, it may be that Windows has blocked it. Try booting back into windows, open up the Device Manager, then find your wireless card, right click, go to Properties, and then go to "Power Management." There should be a checkbox there to allow or dissallow Windows to shut it off for power saving features. Make sure it does NOT have that ability (i had to uncheck the box).

Hopefully that helps anyone who comes across this problem.